# Groovy Closure methods don't take precedence does not seem to get called when in a class

Tags: groovy

I just cannot understand how to get closures to work as I would expect them. For example let's say I have a class

```java
class Bar {
    public void greeting(String name) {
        println "Hello: ${name}"
    }
}
```

When I delegate `Bar` in a `Closure` as such:

```java
class Foo {

    void helloBob(){
        bar {
            greeting("Bob")
        }
    }

    def bar(@DelegatesTo(value = Bar, strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY) Closure cl) {
        cl.rehydrate(new Bar(), this, this)
        cl.call()
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        new Foo().helloBob()
    }
    
}
```

I get the stacktrace when running:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Foo.greeting() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [Bob]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:76)
    at 
    at ...
```

The: `No signature of method: Foo.greeting()` makes no sense to me because it should be calling `Bar.greeting()` as it is in a `Closure` which has `@DelegatesTo(value = Bar`. Why is the closure not referring to `Bar.greeting`? How do I get it to do that? My IDE (IntelliJ) seems to think it's `Bar.greeting` which is what I want, but when I run it I get a stacktrace.

***EDIT***
Weirdly enough if I remove a whole bunch of type information it then seems to work with this:

```java
    Bar bar(closure) {
        def bar = new Bar()
        closure.delegate = bar
//        closure.rehydrate(bar, this, this) // this causes error why?
        closure.call()
        return bar
    }
```

With the IDE happy and all. I also don't understand why I cannot use `rehydrate` it seems to cause an error, yet setting the `delegate` manually is fine.

Comment: rehydrate is typically intended for runtime not user usage. In your own calling code you can just call the property setters of Closure.

Answer (score 1):

Rehydrate doesn't modify the closure - it returns a new copy of it. So call the new closure.

```
cl.rehydrate(new Bar(), this, this).call()
```

Don't forget to set the resolveStrategy to what you are claiming in the annotation.